# Is there a difference between Lang::get('locale') and __('locale') in Laravel?

Tags: multilingual, laravel-5.7

In Laravel 5.7 the docs say to use the following syntax to retrieve locales

```
{{ __ ('my.locale')}}
```

but I noticed

```
{{Lang::get('my.locale')}}
```

works too, and it's in fact what was also used in previous versions.

Is there a fundamental difference between this two, or just the syntax changed?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The main difference is that `__()` and `@lang` will check for [json translation files](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/localization#using-translation-strings-as-keys) in addition to your php language files. Other than that, the syntax hasn't changed; they all defer to the same `\Illuminate\Translation\Translator::get()` method eventually.

These will all work from a Blade view:

```php
@lang('...')
{{ __('...') }}
{{ trans('...') }}
{{ Lang::trans('...') }}
{{ Lang::get('...') }}
{{ app('translator')->get('...') }}
```

If you use the `@lang` Blade directive, keep in mind that it doesn't escape htmlentities, which means your translation strings would need to be stored in their escaped form (e.g. `&lt;&gt;` instead of `<>`). None of the other functions escape htmlentities either, but using `@lang` is the only option in that list that doesn't pass the string through the handlebars `{{ }}`, which is where the escape function is called. It may not be common to have html special characters in a translation string, and translation strings don't usually come from user input (so cross-site scripting isn't an issue), but it's worth knowing.

---

If you want to dive deeper, this is the difference with `__()` (as of Laravel 5.8):

```php
/**
 * Translate the given message.
 *
 * @param  string  $key
 * @param  array  $replace
 * @param  string  $locale
 * @return string|array|null
 */
function __($key, $replace = [], $locale = null)
{
    return app('translator')->getFromJson($key, $replace, $locale);
}
```

You can see it's using `getFromJson()` instead of `get()`. However, `getFromJson()` [falls back to `get()`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.7/src/Illuminate/Translation/Translator.php#L160) if it didn't find anything in your json files:

```php
// If we can't find a translation for the JSON key, we will attempt to translate it
// using the typical translation file. This way developers can always just use a
// helper such as __ instead of having to pick between trans or __ with views.
if (! isset($line)) {
    $fallback = $this->get($key, $replace, $locale);

    if ($fallback !== $key) {
        return $fallback;
    }
}
```

Then there's `trans()`, which is nothing more than an alias for `get()`:

```php
public function trans($key, array $replace = [], $locale = null)
{
    return $this->get($key, $replace, $locale);
}
```

Comment: Alternative to @lang would be {!! trans() !!} in case you need HTML-support in the strings (no escape, security risk, if the input is unsafe)